# ng-repeat loop on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

```
  <span  ng-repeat="s  in colors">
         <p><li><input type="checkbox"   ng-model="colors[id].checked"   ng-change="setColor(s.id)"> &nbsp; {{s.name}}</li></p> 
</span>
```

In my controller,

```
$scope.colorsel= []; 
    $scope.setColor = function(a){
         if($scope.colorsel.indexOf(a) == -1 ){
              $scope.colorsel.push(a);
         }
         else{
             var index =  $scope.colorsel.indexOf(a)
            $scope.colorsel.splice(index,1);

         }
    }
```

Am getting the colorsel values correctly. But if i select one checkbox, it is just showing that all checkboxes are selected(means tick mark appears in all checkboxes but it is taking only the id of the check box which is selected in colorsel array). I f I select other one, all the tick marks will disappear. Plz help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Just reference directly to the object: `ng-model="s.checked"`.

This: `colors[id].checked` is wrong because you reference to the same **id** (Perhaps **s.id** `colors[s.id].checked` is what you're trying). So if you have in your controller `$scope.id = 2` than you always referencing to `colors[2].checked`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<span  ng-repeat="s in colors">
 <p>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="s[id].checked" ng-change="setColor(s.id)"> &nbsp; {{s.name}}
 </p> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat="s  in colors"` is similar as `foreach(s in colors)`
So if you want to access values from colors you need to use "S" inplace of colors.